# Weak Link a third party framework in another framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, dynamic-frameworks

So here is the scenario. I have two Cocoa Touch frameworks lets call it `Framework_A` and `Framework_B` and have respective Cocoa Pods for them `Pod_A` and `Pod_B`.

Now I want `Framework_A` to weakly link to `Framework_B` i.e, If `Framework_B` is present in the project then call a method of `Framework_B`.

How can I achieve this? I'm currently using `__has_include` macro to achieve it as shown below:

```
#if __has_include(< Framework_B/Framework_B.h>)
    #import <Framework_B/Framework_B.h>
#endif
```

But this is causing issue while Submitting build to AppStore where it gives the following error:

```
- ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - One or more dynamic libraries that are referenced by your app are not present in the dylib search path.
– ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - The app submission can not be successfully recompiled from bitcode due to missing symbols during linking.
```

This happens when the `Framework_B` is not present in the project.

Comment: Weak linking is a runtime thing where as `__has_include()` is compile-time. Have you read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html)?

Comment: I'm trying with the help of this doc, will get back on this. Thanks @trojanfoe!

Comment: Hi @ChengappaCD, I have a similar situation, does the _weak_linking helps?